# Trouble assigning variable to getElementById in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working on a practice set where I've created a text field and a button, that when clicked, displays in a div.

When I do it writing everything out fully, it works just fine:

```
<input id ="myInput" type="text">
<button id="stylesChanger">Change the text!</button>
<div id="firstDiv">This is some text</div>

document.getElementById("stylesChanger").onclick = function () {
document.getElementById("firstDiv").innerHTML =
document.getElementById("myInput").value; }
```

However, when I try to assign the elements to variables to shorten everything up, it doesn't work. Why is this?

```
<input id ="myInput" type="text">
<button id="stylesChanger">Change the text!</button>
<div id="firstDiv">This is some text</div>

var myInput = document.getElementById("myInput").value; 
var firstButton = document.getElementById("stylesChanger");       
var firstDiv = document.getElementById("firstDiv").innerHTML; 

firstButton.onclick = function {
    firstDiv = myInput;
}
```

Comment: You shortened `document.getElementById("firstDiv").innerHTML` to `firstDiv` and `document.getElementById("myInput").value` to `myInput` .. those are not the same thing; also, you should escape the value to prevent adding raw HTML into your document or assign to `.textContent` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the `.value` at the exact time of the click and assign to the `.innerHTML` property at that time.  Your code was getting the `.value` and `.innerHTML` at the time of the page initialization and then trying to use those to affect the DOM elements which simply does not work.  `myInput` and `firstDiv` were not object references in your code or live references to what was in those DOM elements - they were simply static string values.

You could use this:

```
<input id ="myInput" type="text">
<button id="stylesChanger">Change the text!</button>
<div id="firstDiv">This is some text</div>

var myInput = document.getElementById("myInput"); 
var firstButton = document.getElementById("stylesChanger");       
var firstDiv = document.getElementById("firstDiv"); 

firstButton.onclick = function {
    firstDiv.innerHTML = myInput.value;
}
```

In general, it is better to NOT cache DOM objects like this code is doing because it just creates an issue for a memory leak (if you ever use dynamic elements) and is simply not needed.  Your original version would be my recommendation here.

---

As a point of further explanation, this is what was happening in your code (read the comments above each line:

```
// get the value in the myInput <input> tag at time of page initialization 
// and store it in myInput Javascript variable
var myInput = document.getElementById("myInput").value; 

// get the stylesChanger DOM element and store it in the firstButton variable
var firstButton = document.getElementById("stylesChanger");       

// get the current string value of the innerHTML in the firstDiv
// and store it in the firstDiv variable
var firstDiv = document.getElementById("firstDiv").innerHTML; 

firstButton.onclick = function {
    // take the static string in the myInput variable and assign it to 
    // the firstDiv variable (does not affect any DOM elements)
    firstDiv = myInput;
}
```

Comment: Added line by line explanation of what your code was doing.

Comment: THANK YOU. This was exactly what I was looking for. I'm still very new at this – would you mind elaborating on this a little more?  "In general, it is better to NOT cache DOM objects like this code is doing because it just creates an issue for a memory leak (if you ever use dynamic elements) and is simply not needed

Comment: @mellamojoe - Storing a DOM element in a global variable creates a permanent reference to that DOM element.  If you changed the HTML in your page such that that DOM element was no longer present in the page, the browser's garbage collector could not free that DOM element because you're still holding a reference to it in your global variable.  That's just not a recommended design pattern.  Plus using globals when globals are not required is also not a recommended design pattern because global variables can easily create conflicts with other code.

Answer (score 0):

Because, in your code, `myInput` and `firstDiv` are string values instead of object references.

Provided that the referenced elements are loaded when your script executes, the correct way to do it would be:

```
var myInput = document.getElementById("myInput"); 
var firstButton = document.getElementById("stylesChanger");       
var firstDiv = document.getElementById("firstDiv"); 

firstButton.onclick = function {
    firstDiv.innerHTML = myInput.value;
}
```